# Web API 2 DataMember naming not working in FromUri parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having issues with DataMember-naming in UriParameters.

```
[DataContract]
public class testobj 
{

[DataMember(Name = "Test")]
public string a {get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "Test1")]
public string b {get; set; }

}
```

Then i have my controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult test([FromUri] testobj testparams)
{
   return testparams;
}
```

In the response i get `Test` and `Test1`, that's correct. However i have to use `a` and `b` in the uriParameters, why can't i use Test and Test1 there?

How can i fix this?

Comment: Have same issue with aspnet core

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an object type in the Query String, You have to pass it in the HTTP Packets Body, and use [FromBody] in your Controller methods Parameter.

here's a Stackoverflow link explaining more, 
[ASP.NET Web APi - Passing an object as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819251/asp-net-web-api-passing-an-object-as-parameter)

Thank You,
Bhadhri