# How to use DataMember Name for [FromQuery] object Asp.Net core, ModelBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding, datacontract

For [FromBody] parameters I can use [DataMember.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.name?view=netframework-4.8) to set custom name of property, but it doesn't work for [FromQuery]. I guess it depends on model binding

I want to process query like `?status=a&status=b&status=c`

with query object `[FromQuery]MyQuery`

```
[DataContract]
class MyQuery {
     [DataMember(Name = "status")
     public IReadOnlyList<string> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

I can do it like

```
class MyQuery {
     [FromQuery("status")
     public IReadOnlyList<string> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

but I would like to avoid model dependency from `AspNetCore`, is there any solutions?

(there is [similar question about Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613159/web-api-2-datamember-naming-not-working-in-fromuri-parameters) but it has not answer)

Comment: `I would like to avoid model dependency from AspNetCore` Do you mean that you'd like to avoid using ASP.NET Core built-in model binding approach? If you can clarify your actual scenario, so that we can understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find way do to it with standart attributes, so I use `statuses` name, use custom attribute for string collections

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
internal class StringCollectionAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

and use custom model binder

```
public class StringCollectionBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private static readonly Type BinderType = typeof(StringCollectionBinder);
    private static readonly Type ModelType = typeof(List<string>);

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var propertyAttributes = (context.Metadata as DefaultModelMetadata)?.Attributes.PropertyAttributes;

        var isStringCollection =
            propertyAttributes?.Any(x => x is StringCollectionAttribute) == true
            && context.Metadata.ModelType.IsAssignableFrom(ModelType);

        return isStringCollection ? new BinderTypeModelBinder(BinderType) : null;
    }
}

public class StringCollectionBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const char ValueSeparator = ',';

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var valueCollection = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);

        if (valueCollection == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueCollection);

        var stringCollection = valueCollection.FirstValue;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringCollection))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var collection = stringCollection.Split(ValueSeparator).ToList();
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(collection);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```